# User-to-user similarity using map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

My collection contains:

```
{ user_id : 1, product_id : 1 },
{ user_id : 1, product_id : 2 },
{ user_id : 1, product_id : 3 },
{ user_id : 2, product_id : 2 },
{ user_id : 2, product_id : 3 },
{ user_id : 3, product_id : 2 },
```

My collection track product viewed by a user where **user_id** is ID of user and **product_id** is ID of product.
I want to compute similarity between two users, e.g. number of product they both viewed.
For example from collection above, similarity between users will be

```
{ user_id1 : 1, user_id2 : 2, similarity : 2 },
{ user_id1 : 1, user_id2 : 3, similarity : 1 },
{ user_id1 : 2, user_id2 : 3, similarity : 1 },
```

### Edited

I've done it without map-reduce

```
def self.build_similarity_weight
  users_id = ProductView.all.distinct(:user_id).to_a
  users_id.each do |user_id|
    this_user_products = ProductView.all.where(user_id: user_id).distinct(:product_id).to_a

    other_users = users_id.map { |e| e } 
    other_users.delete_if { |x| x == user_id }

    other_users.each do |other_uid|
      other_user_products = ProductView.all.where(user_id: other_uid).distinct(:product_id).to_a
      user_sim = (other_user_products & this_user_products).length
      usw = UserSimilarityWeight.new(user_id1: user_id, user_id2: other_uid, weight: user_sim)
      usw.save
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is my code is not efficient, **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, where **n** is number of users.
How can I make my code more efficient using map-reduce?

Regards,

Comment: Also, I feel that map-reduce is a bad choice for this task.

Comment: Actually I haven't try solve my problem with map-reduce. I'm new to map-reduce. I just learn some simple (simpler than my problem) code from [The Little MongoDB Book](http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf) and I barely grasp the concept.

Comment: Well, I suppose, you should learn some more :) And try to solve your problem with whatever knowledge you have.

Comment: Yes. SO is not a place to outsource simple programming tasks.

Comment: I've revised my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do 2 mapreduces.

1. - map: Omit product_id as key and user_id as value
   - reduce: iterate with loop within a loop the value list (list of user ids for each product) and omit as key pair of user ids (where the smallest user id is the first one) and value 1
2. (working on the result of the first map reduce)

   - map: just pass the pair of users as key and the value of 1 as value
   - reduce: sum the value for each pair.

Second, you can't be more efficient than O(n2) because your result is of order of O(n2).
Meaning, even if in some magically way, you will get the pairs and the similarity, you still need to write n^2 of pairs.